# Optional INT parameter in Web API Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create an API method in an ASP.NET Core app that may or may not receive an integer input parameter. I have the following code but getting an error with this. What am I doing wrong?

```
// GET: api/mycontroller/{id}
[HttpGet("id:int?")]
public IActionResult Get(int id = 0)
{
   // Some logic here...
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Just added the error in the original post.

Comment: Not overly familiar with asp.net core and don't have a dev. env handy, but I suspect it should be like this: `"{id?:int}"` whereby you are indicating that `id` is optional and the type is `int`. So you are missing the `{` and `}` and also the `?` is in the wrong place as far as I can tell.

Comment: According to Microsoft documentation, mine is the correct syntax: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Comment: Yes, I see, however the problem is for sure the missing `{` and `}`, because I just tested it and it works fine with `{` and `}` but without them I see the same error. So it should be `"{id:int?}`...otherwise "id:int?" is being treated as a literal string, not a route template.

Comment: Yes! The curly braces were missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"id:int?"` is not a valid route template, it's just a string literal (like as if you expected the Request Url to literally look like `http://server/api/MyController/id:int?` which is not allowed.
Funnily enough, that's only because of the `?` character; if you removed that then the literal would be allowed (even though it's useless).

Whereas `"{id:int?}"` is a proper route template and will work correctly, i.e. the Url will look like `http://server/api/MyController/42` or `http://myserver/api/MyController/` which will give the default value

So the method should be like this:

```
// GET: api/mycontroller/{id}
[HttpGet("{id:int?}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id = 0)
{
   // Some logic here...
}
```